# How to highlight last html-element with specific css class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to highlight last div with `class="block"` in the following html-structure, if the number of `div` with `class="block"` is unknown? (With help of css-selectors)

http://codepen.io/Feel_codepen/pen/Ifjzd

There, for example, I can highlight third div.

Comment: Please add the relevant code and markup to your question, don't let us follow a link...

Comment: How to do it for the following html-structure? http://codepen.io/Feel_codepen/pen/Ifjzd

Comment: Did you just updated your question? Why? And why didn't you followed up my advice?

Comment: This is my first question there and I do mistake in html-structure that i attach to question. Therefore I update my question.

Comment: It is preferred to have the html IN this question not in an external site. See [this answer on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89309/158100)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using [:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type)

```
div.block:last-of-type{
 color:yellow;
}
```

[**CodepenDemo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BDCxH)

Answer (score 1):

Use `last-child`:

```
.main .block:last-child{
    background-color:#FCC;
    /* Your styles*/
}
```

[<kbd>CodePen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hdygo)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:last-child` selector.

More information could be found at http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

```
.main .block:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpqad

Answer (score 0):

By using the last-child pseudo class

```
.block:last-child{
   background-color: yellow; /* or some other color */
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.block:last-child
{
background-color:blue;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rhbum)

Answer (score 0):

And Magic!

```
.main>div[class=block]:last-child{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

this should do it :P i hope

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
$("div:last-child").addClass("last-child");
```

With this you can add a css class to the last child of a certain div or element